# Java web application for multiple users

Tags: concurrency, web

I need to design and implement a Java web application that can be used by multiple users at the same time. The data that is handled by this application is going to be huge and may take about 5 minutes for a page to display the results(database records).

I had designed this application using HTML, Servlets and JSP. But when two users would try to get the records, only one user was able to view the results while the other faced an error.

I always thought a web application would take care of handling multiple users but this is not the case.

Any insights on this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: :Can you be a lil more explicit about the issue

Comment: What database and database abstraction (hibernate?) you are using, what framework (struts?) and what application server (tomcat/jboss/jetty) are you using? Please show us the errors, the application server is showing.

Comment: I didnt use any frameworks. A jsp page would be directed to a servlet which would perform business logic and redirect to another jsp page. Now the business logic is present inside another java class. For getting the records,I do not access the database directly.I just make HttpUrlConnection(post) calls to get the data.This request goes and hits a server to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

What are are using to develop this web-application?  If you are developing it in your own way from the start I must say you are trying to re-invent the same wheel which has been already created and enhanced by very solid frameworks.

I suggest you analyze your requirements thoroughly and study some available frameworks.  Let them handle the things like multi threading and other aspects in the best possible manner.

Handling multiple request at a time is a container work and as an application developer we have to concentrate how we are handling and processing those requret being forwarded by the container.

I must suggest you to get some insight how web-application work and how request -response cycle happens

Comment: I didnt use any frameworks. A jsp page would be directed to a servlet which would perform business logic and redirect to another jsp page. Now the business logic is present inside another java class. For getting the records,I do not access the database directly.I just make HttpUrlConnection(post) calls to get the data.This request goes and hits a server to fetch the data.

Comment: @ITAmateur You doing it Just to learn how flow goes or you planning to use it in production, since i can no imagine such design to work in real time application.All than you have to do is to write controller request/response handler and other processors.

Comment: I had already implemented it this way and it worked fine as long as one user was trying to get the results. The problem occurred when two people tried to hit the application at the same time. This application has already been deployed at the production site. But I am facing this simultaneous multi-user issue. Could it be because I havent used any framework like Struts or could it the problem of the HttpUrlConnection(post)method failing to send two post requests at the same time? What would be the idea way to develop a web application that supports multi-user?

Comment: @ITAmateur just look at DB side also if everything is working fine as what Michael Borgwardt suggest in his answer

Answer (score 0):

> I always thought a web application would take care of handling multiple users but this is not the case.

They do if they're written correctly. Obviously yours is not. That's all we can tell you unless you give more information, most importantly details of the error shown to the second user.

One possibility is that everything is OK on the web layer but your DB access for the first user causes an exclusive lock so that the second user cannot access the data at the same time. This could be fixed by using non-exclusive read locks. How to do that depends mainly on what DB you're using.

Getting concurrency right requires you to choose the correct tools and use them correctly. It doesn't just happen magically because it's a web app.

Comment: I didnt use any frameworks. A jsp page would be directed to a servlet which would perform business logic and redirect to another jsp page. Now the business logic is present inside another java class. For getting the records,I do not access the database directly.I just make HttpUrlConnection(post) calls to get the data.This request goes and hits a server to fetch the data.

Comment: @ITAmateur: All of that could be done wrong (mainly by using static fields) but if it's done right it should not cause concurrency issues. The most important information is still missing: what exactly is the error you're seeing? Also, what is processing those HTTP posts your code makes? And what is the underlying Database?